# setting breakpoints with nosetests --pdb option

Tags: python, testing, nose, pdb

`nosetests --pdb` let's me halt upon error or failure, but this is too late for my needs. Stepping through code during execution helps me debug where the problem is.

However, nosetests are helpful as they allow tests that rely on relative imports (i.e. tests in a package).

How can I set breakpoints before the tests are executed?
Currently I'm using:

```
python -m pdb /path/to/my/nosetests testfile.py
```

This solution isn't adequate. Nosetests interfere with pdb output, and my keyboard controls (e.g. arrow keys) are broken.

Using import pdb; pdb.set_trace() would seem like a good idea, however nosetests is blocking my access to the pdb console.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can add

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

anywhere in your source that you want to stop in the debugger.

Make sure you pass `-s` to nose so that it does not capture `stdout`.

Comment: I was just about to add this to my question. This isn't an acceptable solution either. When using this with nosetests, it's apparent this is literally unusable as access to the pdb console is screened, and no pdb commands can be executed.

Comment: Add the -s flag to nosetests to prevent it from capturing stdout, and you'll be able to use pdb just fine.

Comment: Does not work. 
Use this: `from nose.tools import set_trace; set_trace()`

Answer (score 149):

Even better than remembering to use `-s` is to use the `set_trace` variant that comes with Nose. Add

```
from nose.tools import set_trace; set_trace()
```

wherever you'd like to break in to the debugger. The stdin/out redirection will be taken care of for you. The only strange side effect I've run into is the inability to restart your code from within pdb (using `run`) while debugging during a nose run.

Comment: Is there any documentation of this? How to move out of the loop?

Comment: You mean how to navigate once you've got `pdb` running? I'm sure there are docs, but off the top of my head- `s` "steps into" a function call, `n` goes to the "next" statement, `u` moves "up" the stack, and `d` moves "down". You can use `b` to set breakpoints and `c` to "continue" and quit the stepping debugger. Hope that helps!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It provides all the regular functionality of the original pdb.set_trace() command.

Comment: Any possibility for an ipython/ipdb version of this?

Answer (score 5):

If you have **ipython**, for unlimited awesomeness use:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

*unlimited awesomeness: just like ipython - auto-completion, coloring etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **pytest**, you can use

```
import pytest; pytest.set_trace()
```

See [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/usage.html#setting-a-breakpoint-aka-set-trace).